# Where would xhr.send be defined in order to POST user data to an API?

Tags: php, angular, captcha

My app is failing at reCaptcha validation. The only error remaining is illustrated in screenshot 1.

Can anyone help me understand if this is just a matter of the xhr.send variable not being defined? If so, where would that need defining? Sorry - am not a developer and just trying to establish the scope of my problem to keep researching.

Screenshot 1: [Error from the Network perspective of my Chrome web developer tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmmh2.jpg)

Screenshot 2: [Specific error in my angular.js file with reference to xhr.send](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA0Y2.jpg)

Here is the code of my captcha validation PHP file:

```
    <?php

  $postData = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $request = json_decode($postData);

  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

echo json_encode(isValid($request->captchaResponse));
exit;

function isValid($response) {
    try {
        $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
        $data = [
            'secret' => 'mykeyishere',
            'response' => $response
        ];

        $options = [
            'http' => [
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data)
            ]
        ];

        $context = stream_context_create($options);
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        return json_decode($result);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        return null;
    }
}

?>
```

Adding Header information as requested:
[Header Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpsg9.jpg)

Comment: Can you add a content of **Headers** tab of your Chrome dev tools for the failed request please?

Comment: why the `json_decode` in the `isValid` function and then `json_encode` ? Also, remove the `\r\n` from the end of the `Content-Type` header. The question title references `xhr.send` but you have not shown the javascript - is that where you believe the issue is?

Comment: It looks like your server not respond with proper `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header on pre-flight request from your client code, because you are sending JSON with POST request.

Comment: @dajnz added the header information. The "Response" tab says "This request has no response data available"

Comment: @RamRaider this is an inherited application I'm just trying to get back to working order. Do not know the original reasons for your questions but thank you for looking at it. Will try removing the \r\n\ as suggested.

Comment: Ok, so the reason for this issue is not related to CORS since you are sending requests within the same origin. But I see from the response headers that you are using **ecstatic** server which is based on Express for Node, right? What webserver is on your backend?

Comment: @dajnz apache2 locally (Debian) but hosted on linode publicly

Comment: @shermski4 so you see this issue only when your app is on your remote server, or locally as well? I just tried to send test requests to your remote Linode server, but it looks not accessible/available, can you enable it for a while to allow me check it?

Comment: @dajnz yes ill restart it momentarily. disclaimer: I did copy the code from a production instance and use a Linode Debian host to re-create it as a test environment. I am wondering if web server and other differences in the new host are complicating things. again - not a developer but very much appreciate the support.

Comment: @dajnz do not have a method of testing locally (my Debian host via Linode is shell only - no web browser).

Comment: @shermski4 still cannot connect, have you restarted it? If no, let me know when you will do. And this is the correct link, right: http://li1252-85.members.linode.com:8080/assets/captcha/validate.php

Comment: @dajnz please try now had to add UFW rule to open it up.

Comment: @shermski4 Ok, it works now, I'm checking it. By the way, your webserver is likely configured not properly, because on **GET** request it just returns your PHP script as a file, but not executes it with PHP interpreter. Can you add your Apache config used for your app?

Comment: @dajnz having trouble finding my http config file in any directory :( will reply back as soon as i do.

Comment: Ok, I would say that your app is not working under Apache web server, instead, it uses Node.js-based webserver (likely Express.js), and static files are served by [Ecstatic static file server middleware](https://github.com/jfhbrook/node-ecstatic) (this is how it identifies itself: `Node.js v8.15.0/ ecstatic server running @ li1252-85.members.linode.com:8080`). And since it is Node-based web server, it is not configured to handle PHP scripts properly, and all your PHP scripts are returned as plain text. And the reason of this 405 HTTP error is due to the config of this Node-based server.

Comment: For Express.js you can define what request methods and what routes to serve, and others will be responded as 404 (for allowed request methods), or 405 (for not allowed request methods).

Comment: @dajnz thank you so much for your help. I'll dig into express materials or just see if I can use Apache instead.

Comment: @shermski4 you're welcome. If you don't mind I'll put my comments above as the correct answer for your question?

Comment: @dajnz please do. thanks again.

Comment: Update - transferred to apache2 and it worked like a charm. As @danjz stated, the native (at the time of development) nodejs webserver wasnt configured to handle the php captcha validation. Apache2 did so out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

As I checked your app is not working under Apache web server, instead, it uses Node.js-based webserver (likely Express.js), and static files are served by [Ecstatic static file server middleware](https://github.com/jfhbrook/node-ecstatic) (this is how it identifies itself: `Node.js v8.15.0/ ecstatic server running @ li1252-85.members.linode.com:8080`). And since it is a Node-based web server, it is not configured to handle PHP scripts properly, and all your PHP scripts are returned as plain text.

And the reason of this 405 HTTP error is due to the config of this Node-based server. For Express.js you can define what request methods and what routes to serve, and others will be responded as 404 (for allowed request methods), or 405 (for not allowed request methods).